# Vulcanize and html <base>

Tags: gulp, html-imports, vulcanize

I have a file (`index.html`) in my `app/` folder in a project. It contains a `<base href="/">` tag as well as some imports from `app/bower_components/`. As part of my distribution process, I use Gulp to move the code from `app/` to `dist/`, and then run `vulcanize` on it via `polybuild`. `index.html` makes it into the `dist/` directory, as does `bower_components/`, but when vulcanize gets it, it tries to open the first import:

`<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>`

Instead of looking in `dist/bower_components/…` (or just `bower_components/…`, relative to the `dist/index.html` file), however, it looks for `/.index.html/bower_components/…`. How do I stop it from using this and use the relative URL as written in the original code? Commenting out the `<base>` tag solves the issue.

Gulp Task (from Polymer Starter Kit):

```
gulp.task('vulcanize', function () {
  return gulp.src('dist/index.html')
  .pipe(polybuild({maximumCrush: true}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Comment: cant comment unless I see your gulp setup

Comment: Gulp task added. Note that the use of the command line vulcanize command returns the original HTML file, with the link written as `../../../../../.index.html/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js`. It is treating `<base href="/">` as `/` on the filesystem.